# Apache HTTP to HTTPS Redirect working for alias but not server name

Tags: apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, 301-redirect

I have created an SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt.
The certificate has been installed and is referenced in the Apache config file.
The Apache config provides a ServerName (e.g., example.com) and a ServerAlias (e.g., www.example.com).  Both are referenced in the SSL certificate as verified by the output from the `certbot certificates` command.

The Apache config also contains a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.
`RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1`

The problem is that the redirect is only happening for the alias (www.example.com). Requests to example.com result in a simple 200 OK response.

**Request to alias:**

```
$ curl -I www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2020 19:13:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Length: 325
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**Request to the actual ServerName value:**

```
curl -I example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2020 19:16:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sun, 23 Feb 2020 00:03:31 GMT
ETag: "2aa6-59f32fc296ba5"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 10918
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

The `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>` sections of the config file are identical except for the redirect in the *:80 section and the SSL lines in the *:443 section:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

Am I missing something obvious or have I just gone far awry? :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! :-) Posting the answer here in case some other poor soul makes the same mistake that I did.

Turns out that there was a `<VirtualHost *:80>` entry in `000-default.conf` with the same server name (`ServerName example.com`). The `000-default.conf` file does not include the SSL configuration directives.

It appears that if the same `ServerName` shows up in more than one enabled Apache config file, which entry takes precedence is indeterminate.

I simply changed the `ServerName` directive in `000-default.conf` to include a host name and restarted Apache. Problem solved.